# Future of the SAP RFC SDK

Tags: .net, sdk, sap-erp, saprfc

Is the SAP RFC SDK (wdtfuncs.ocx, wdtlog.ocx respectively Interop.SAPFunctionsOCX.dll, Interop.SAPLogonCtrl.dll) an acceptable / recommended way to connect (Microsoft) applications via RFCs with SAP ? Will there be a support and maintenance of the SDK in the future (especially in ECC 6.0) ?
Are there people who use these controls in .NET applications ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have good news for you. SAP plans to release a **new version of the SAP.NET Connector**. See http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAPConn/ABAP+Connectivity+Home

Comment: Fantastic news! I can't believe it! It's like christmas! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0 released.](http://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2010/12/sap-connector-for-microsoft-net-30.html)
The NCo 3.0 can be downloaded from [SAP Service Marketplace](https://websmp209.sap-ag.de/~form/sapnet?_SHORTKEY=01100035870000719347&), including accompanying documentation.